# Are table captions expected to be placed below the tables in the article class?

Tags: tables, article

In the `article` class, is table caption supposed to go below the table?

Common practice in academic writing is that table captions should go above the table; does the `article` class (I checked also `book`) assume the opposite?

The question is **not** of how to place the caption above the table nor why it should be above the table. The question is about the usage assumed by the `article` class. Where is it documented? Why did the authors chose this behavior contrary to common academic practice?

In the code below, the second table (with the caption below) looks to me better than the first one (with the caption above), which makes me think that this is the expected use of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Sample caption}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
Some & columns\\
\hline
Value & 1\\
Value & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\hline
Some & columns\\
\hline
Value & 1\\
Value & 2\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sample caption}
\end{table}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

while change first line to `amsart` or Springer's `llncs`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
```

gives what looks correct to me -- the first table looks natural and the second (correctly) wrong:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike some extended float systems (for example the `float` package) `article` captions are not positioned by the class they just appear where you place `\caption`, also the default styling is very simple and the same for `table` and `figure`.

The class has two lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` which default to 10pt and 0pt (whatever size option is used).  For tables with captions above, you probably want to set `\belowcaptionskip` non zero.

Comment: Thank you David! I know _how_ to position the captions; the question is **why** the authors chose 10pt and 0pt and not the other way around, contrary to the academic tradition. Or, maybe you can just confirm my feeling that it was an incorrect choice and that every user of these classes should first thing swap these two values for the paper to look professional.

Comment: Ah! probably this is the answer: "styling is very simple and the same for table and figure", so the authors did not _care_ about tables, right?

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh author not author**s** and in 1985 when this was set up just having two parameters was more than enough customisation than could  be afforded having that change automatically depending on float type might have used up all the memory tex had for macro space. even by 1993/4 when we updated things for latex2e, we were having to count bytes and the number of defined macros. so _not care_ isn't the wording I'd use.

Answer (score 2):

It will be enough to  load the `caption` package, which will automatically permute the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `belowcaptionskip`.

Comment: Thank you! The question was not _how_ but whether there was a _reason_ behind this decision. Probably David gave the answer: they did not care about tables?

Comment: The `caption` package seems to make `\belowcaptionskip` a synonym of `\abovecaptionskip`. With `\usepackage{caption}`, both captions below and above the table look OK. If I say `\setlength\abovecaptionskip=0pt`, then both seem to become zero and both captions below and above the table look incorrect.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Itseems to be a little more complex. See § 2.6 of the documentation.